# How to obtain affine transform with some points fixed?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, linear-algebra, affinetransform

For example I have 4 points in one coordinate system and 4 points in another coordinate system, if I estimate affine transform in naive way corner points [points 1,4] will not precisely warp to corresponding corner points in another coordinate system.

How to obtain affine transform with limitation that some points should warp on corresponding points in another coordinate system?

Comment: I recommend you use NumPy. If you are in R2 for example, you can have a matrix [[a,b], [c,d]] native in NumPy that can perform affine transformations on (x,y) without any problems. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/index.html

Comment: Can you provide some example with current results and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need to recover affine transform, when images of 4 certain points are known.
I think, the following code may help you (sorry for bad codestyle -- I'm mathematician, not programmer)

```py
import numpy as np
# input data
ins = np.array([[1, 1, 2], [2, 3, 0], [3, 2, -2], [-2, 2, 3]]) # <- primary system
out = np.array([[0, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [-2, -1, 6], [4, 1, -3]]) # <- secondary system
p = np.array([1, 2, 3]) #<- transform this point
# finding transformation
l = len(ins)
e = lambda r,d: np.linalg.det(np.delete(np.vstack([r, ins.T, np.ones(l)]), d, axis=0))
M = np.array([[(-1)**i * e(R, i) for R in out.T] for i in range(l+1)])
A, t = np.hsplit(M[1:].T/(-M[0])[:,None], [l-1])
t = np.transpose(t)[0]
# output transformation
print("Affine transformation matrix:\n", A)
print("Affine transformation translation vector:\n", t)
# unittests
print("TESTING:")
for p, P in zip(np.array(ins), np.array(out)):
  image_p = np.dot(A, p) + t
  result = "[OK]" if np.allclose(image_p, P) else "[ERROR]"
  print(p, " mapped to: ", image_p, " ; expected: ", P, result)
# calculate points
print("CALCULATION:")
P = np.dot(A, p) + t
print(p, " mapped to: ", P)
```

This code demonstrates how to recover affine transformation as matrix + vector and tests that initial points are mapped to where they should. You can test this code with [Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb), so you don't have to install anything.

Regarding theory behind this code: it is based on equation presented in "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)", matrix recovery is described in section "Recovery of canonical notation" and number of points needed to pinpoint the exact affine transformation is discussed in "How many points do we need?" section. The same authors published "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner%27s_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)" that contains many practical examples of this kind.

Comment: Please don’t post the same answer multiple times. Instead, flag the question as a duplicate. This answer is nearly identical to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56228667/7328782

Comment: Many thanks! I'm a newbie to stackowerflow, I don't actually know how to flag duplicates (can't find any button or whatever). Probably this requires reputation to be higher than certain value, thus this feature is inaccessible to me.

Comment: You’re right, flagging requires 15 points. You should now have enough rep for that. :)

Comment: Thanks :) Now I flagged it, should I remove the answer or do nothing and just leave everything to moderators?