# 3D point cloud registration with Rotation/Scale/Shear/Translation extraction (know correspondances)

Tags: python, 3d, registration

I have two 3D points cloud with correspondances between points.
I'm trying to find the best affine transformation between this two cloud, and I want to obtain finally:
- Rotation
- Shear
- Scale
- Translation

Curently i'm using Coherent point drift, but i know there is a better solution with probably mean square (probably procustes analysis) but with this solution I don't know how it is possible to extract more than only scale and rotation.

And there is a librairie to do this easily in python3 ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find affine transformation matrix between two sets of 3D points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166088/how-to-find-affine-transformation-matrix-between-two-sets-of-3d-points)

Comment: Is there such a matrix that transforms all? Or are you looking for a best fit?

Comment: You could also try a 9-dimensional optimization  where each coefficient of the matrix is optimized.

Comment: Hi @Joe, thank you for your quick answer ! 
I saw this first link and yes that's really interesting, i found that too
https://lucidar.me/en/mathematics/calculating-the-transformation-between-two-set-of-points/
But I have a new question .. How can we estimate shearing ? 
I find many answers for rotation/translation/scaling but no one for shearing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362043/shear-matrix-as-a-combination-of-basic-transformation

Comment: That's the inverse: https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~fricke/projects/israel/paeth/rotation_by_shearing.html

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition